# C++ copy constructor vs overloaded assignment vs constructor best practices?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

this is more of an opinion/best practices question.

I'm new to C++ and I'm currently working on a program that uses dynamically allocated strings.  I finally get the difference between the constructors, the copy constructors and overloaded assignment operator.  I also get the need for a destructor for these objects.

(I'm building an exam object that holds question objects that hold an array of T/F answer objects, each point to dynamic storage for the strings).

Here's my question:  What is considered best practices in the professional world for creating these object?  As I sit here and think about this, I can gather information from the user and store those values in temporary locations and instantiate the question objects with the constructor, or I can build each object using the copy and assignment methods... I'm not sure what to do.  Is one method better than the other?  Should I build and test all three?  Please help.

Comment: The best practice would be to use `std::vector` and/or `std::unqiue_ptr`, and leaving your class with the default destructor and copy/move constructors (rule of zero)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice in this case is to not manage resources yourself. Use the standard library (`std::string` and `std::vector`/`std::map` in this case). Something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Exam {
public:
  std::map<std::string, std::string> questions_;
};
```

`std::string` does the resource management for you. When its destructor is called, it'll clean up behind it. The same goes for `std::map` or `std::vector`.

The magic here is that the members in all 3 classes (`std::string`, `std::map`, `Exam`) are guaranteed to be properly disposed as they go out of scope, per [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). So, if you use it like:

```
void foo() {
  Exam e;
  e.questions_["6 x 7 = ?"] = "42";
} // Here, you're guaranteed that all storage for all your questions and answers is disposed.
```

you don't have to worry about writing constructors, destructors, or managing heap-allocated objects.

Generally, I'd recommend trying to avoid writing `new` and `delete` in your programs at all. If you need dynamic allocation in a use-case that doesn't fit well with containers, use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. Try to abide by the [Law of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) as much as you can.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer.  I guess I have a lot more learning to do.  I'm sort of following a course outline that is teaching me how all this stuff works and isn't "real world" acceptable based on what you've written.  (which makes sense on why my assignment notes are all written so bizarrely). So my question probably reflects my lack of understanding still.  At least I learned what it is I'm trying to do, instead of what's considered best practices.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2470057 if you do want to manage your own resources, instead of using `std::string`, best practice is to have one object per resource.  So instead of your constructor having three `new` expressions, your class should have 3 objects (possibly of the same class as each other), each of which has a single `new` expression in its constructor.